# How to add the node name in warning or fatal message?

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because I use a launch file to launch many nodes.
If there exist any method to output the message with corresponding node name,
it will be easier to debug.
Thank you~

example of unknown node name

```
 [ WARN] [1310816065.685614719]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1310816065.6855, global_pose stamp: 1310816065.0186, tolerance: 0.3000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10613/how-to-add-the-node-name-in-warning-or-fatal-message?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check section 7 of [rosconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole). You can include the node name in the output format.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-16**:
Thanks~~I figured out the answer such as : export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='${severity}:${node}:${file}:${function}:${time}:${message}'